# Event receiver on navigation items changed

Tags: navigation, event-receivers

I want no headings and no pages/lists/document libraries on my navigation, as the sites subsites and other items are created. So Is there any events available for navigation items changing ? So that i can control the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you create a new site, page, library, or list you have the option to not display them in quicklaunch. Pages being the exception, but that can be configured in the Navigation settings page on each site.

If you don't want it by default at all, you can always edit your masterpage in sharepoint designer and find the control "TopNavigationMenuV4" (in SP2010) and set it's properties `StaticDisplayLevels` and `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` to display 1 or 0 levels. Same goes for the quicklaunch control "CurrentNav" (same properties).